# How to validate Stripe subscription is active and paid

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

First time using Stripe's API. What Stripe Webhook events should I use to ensure a user subscription is active and paid for and how should I store it in my database?

I was thinking to set up a Webhook for `invoice.paid` and then inserting the `period_end` datetime into my database and running something like

```
if ( $period_end < date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) {
    //treat subscription as inactive
} else {
    //treat subscription as active
}
```

Is that an advisable way to ensure a subscription is active (paid for)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

1. customer.subscription.updated
2. invoice.payment_failed
3. invoice.payment_succeeded

You need to use `customer.subscription.updated` event to handle the case when first time user subscribes to your product.

then use of `invoice.payment_failed` will inform you about the successful payment of auto payment for subscription and use of `invoice.payment_failed` will inform you that auto payment for your subscription is failed.

If you want to check if your subscription is active then you can use `stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id);`

Comment: So just store in binary value if the subscription is active or not in my database? But if the user cancels the subscription 1/2 though the billing cycle, they still need to have access until the end date, because they paid for it already. And if I run checks on the subscription that will be a super slow if I do that for every page load.

Comment: Stripe gives you one extra parameter called `cancel_at_period_end` which will be true when user cancels the plan and and it is by default false.

Comment: So your recommendation is to just store a binary value of if the subscription is active or not in my database and update it to inactive it on invoice.payment_failed event. Is there a reason you recommend doing it this way instead of how I was going to do it above?

Comment: You were saying to use invoice.paid which is not the event to be used with subscriptions. Storing subscription end period to your db would be too complicated for you to handle it.
Stripe offers grace period after failed payments. If you only use end date to check if subscription is active then even if subscription is not expired by stripe then subscription will not be considered active from your db.

Comment: One more thing you can do if you want to store subscription details to your db. Store all fields like `cancel_at_period_end`, `status`, `current_period_end` to see if your subscription is active. If subscription period is past due then it means that payment for subscription is failed and user is in grace period.